# SVGO config file

Tags: node.js, svgo

With svgo 1.3.2 I used to run this command :

> svgo --pretty --disable={removeUnusedNS,removeUselessDefs,removeUselessStrokeAndFill} file.svg -o file.min.svg

I updated to svgo 2.3.0 and now I get :

> error: unknown option '--disable={removeUnusedNS,removeUselessDefs,removeUselessStrokeAndFill}'

So I tried to create a svgo.config.js like this :

```
const { extendDefaultPlugins } = require('svgo');
module.exports = {
  plugins: extendDefaultPlugins([
    {
      name: 'removeUnusedNS',
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: 'removeUselessDefs',
      active: false
    },
    {
      name: 'removeUselessStrokeAndFill',
      active: false
    }
  ])
}
```

but I just get the error :

> Error: Cannot find module 'svgo'
>
> > Require stack:
> > C:\Users\jpprade\Documents\vrac\svgo.config.js
> > C:\Users\jpprade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\svgo\lib\svgo-node.js
> > C:\Users\jpprade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\svgo\lib\svgo\coa.js
> > C:\Users\jpprade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\svgo\bin\svgo
> >
> > - at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
> > - at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
> > - at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
> > - at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> > - at Object. (C:\Users\jpprade\Documents\vrac\svgo.config.js:1:34)
> > - at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
> > - at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
> > - at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
> > - at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
> > - at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)

svgo is install (globaly)

How can I run svgo with those 3 plugins disabled using to config file (or not) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output when you run `svgo -v`?

It is possible that you are inside a project that has an older version as a dependency which takes precedence over the global **svgo** package.

You can try require using the absolute path to **svgo** 2.3.0.
For instance mine was like that `require('/home/nili/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/svgo');`

I think it could also be in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/svgo` if you installed it as root.

Comment: thanks it worked by using the absolute path : `C:\Users\jpprade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\svgo`